# Does Kapalua Airport (JHM) have a TSA checkpoint?

Tags: airports, tsa, hawaii, maui

I took a plane from Kapalua Airport (JHM) to Honolulu (HNL) on 2019-01-27. I didn't go though the TSA at JHM. I wonder whether the absence of TSA is due to the current US shutdown. Does Kapalua Airport (JHM) have no TSA checkpoint?

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapalua_Airport:

> On November 15, 2016, Hawaiian Airlines announced that it was temporarily suspending sales of its Honolulu to West Maui service pending securing a TSA presence at Kapalua Airport.
>
> On January 11, 2017, Hawaiian Airlines announced they expect to resume service at Kapalua West Maui Airport by late March.

It's unclear me whether  Hawaiian Airlines decided to resume services at JHM because JHM secured TSA presence or because Hawaiian Airlines changed their mind.

Comment: I have no idea which alternative might be correct. But Hawaii Airlines does fly to and from West Maui, and some or many US small regional airports that provide scheduled commercial flights on low-capacity aircraft don't have TSA checkpoints.

Comment: I took a plane from Kapalua Airport (JHM) to Honolulu (HNL) on 2019-01-27. I didn't go though the TSA at JHM.  -- where did you land at HNL, if you had a ticket and no checked in luggage would you have been able to continue to the mainland?

Comment: @chx I landed in terminal 3. Unsure whether I could have continued to mainland. I didn't have any checked-in luggage.

Comment: Hi Frank! HA started selling tickets JHM - HNL (on Nov. 2, 2016) prior to informing TSA. TSA needs advance notice in order to re-federalize an airport, ((JHM was de-federalized in 2013 when Island Air ceased operations and the checkpoint was dismantled and the equipment redeployed). HA had to halt ticket sales and issue refunds until TSA could give them a timeline for re-federalization. Once TSA developed a plan to re-federalize the airport, effective Feb. 19, 2017, HA was able to resume ticket sales, and the first  TSA screened HA flight departed JHM bound for HNL in early March, 2017.

Comment: USDA operates an inspection station at JHM from 0730 to 1345. PAX departing on flights after 1345 will be unable to interline their bags to U.S. mainland destinations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You flew on Mokulele Airlines which operates 9 seat Cessna Caravans and does not require TSA screening. You landed at "Terminal 3" at HNL (in quotes because it is a trailer located 1 1/2 miles from the Main Terminal with no direct access to any other airline). To travel on via a connecting flight you would have had to take a shuttle to the main terminal where you would pass through TSA security.

Had you flown 'Ohana Airlines operated by Hawai'ian Air which uses 49 seat ATR 42-500 aircraft from JHM to HNL, you would have passed through TSA security at JHM and arrive at the main terminal at HNL, requiring no additional TSA screening to catch a connecting flight, assuming you either had carry on luggage only, or had checked your baggage through to your final destination when you checked in at JHM.

You did not notice the TSA checkpoint because it is manned only when 'Ohana flights are departing, which is 4 flights a day at 0830, 1030, 1330, & 1730.

Comment: P.S. I just edited the JHM Wikipedia page to include the security procedures at JHM airport.

Comment: Thanks for the Wikipedia edit and this informed answer!

Answer (score 1):

On March 25 2020 Hawai'ian Airlines suspended it's 'Ohana service to and from Kapalua  Airport  as part of its systemwide reduction in service in response to the COVID-19 pandemic and it doesn't look like it will resume anytime soon. In addition Mokulele Airlines has reduced its service from 10 flights a day to three with Honolulu service only. 'Ohana continues to operate a reduced schedule between Honolulu and Lana'i and Moloka'i.